# How do I deserialize a very simple list of integers?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have (or will have; its not written yet) a .NET web API controller method that I was just going to have return a list of ints as a JSON response. On the client side, I just wanted to deserialize the ints to a List. I tried to use { [1,2,3,4] }, but that's not valid JSON apparently. If I do { "ids" : [1,2,3,4] }, it doesn't deserialize to a simple list. I know I can create a super simple class for this, but I was hoping to avoid that. Is there a solution for this? Thanks!

```
var ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(jsonResult1);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just want a simple list, your JSON should be a simple array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

That should properly deserialize into a `List<int>`:

```
var ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>("[1, 2, 3, 4]");
```

Comment: Ug! I was so close! I thought the outer curly braces were required no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<int> ids = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<int>>(jsonResult1);
```